# How to aggregate data with condition using two arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have M and W data sets and the structure is as follow:

```
M = [
 'ModuleName': 'GDD',
 {Fields: [
    {'FieldID': 5, 'Date': '2018-12-01'},
    {'FieldID': 6, 'Date': '2018-12-01'}
   ]
 }
]

W = [
      {'FieldID': 5, 'Value': 10, 'WDate': 2018-06-05'},
      {'FieldID': 5, 'Value': 10, 'WDate': 2018-06-05'},
      {'FieldID': 6, 'Value': 50, 'WDate': 2018-07-05'},
      {'FieldID': 6, 'Value': 20, 'WDate': 2018-09-05'}
    ]
```

I want to calculate value of all fields from W data set and group by `FieldID` with date condition from M data set.

```
M.forEach(m => {
  if (m.ModuleName === 'GDD') {
    m.Fields.forEach(f => {
      const sum = W.map(w => w.Value).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
    });
  }
});
```

**Condition:** If Date from `M.Fields` is equal or more than date from `W.wDate`.

Since the data sets are huge, I also need to consider efficiency.

The expected output is to add another property and store sum of Value in the m.Fields field object.

```
M = [
 'ModuleName': 'GDD',
 {Fields: [
    {'FieldID': 5, 'Date': '2018-10-01', 'sum': 20},
    {'FieldID': 6, 'Date': '2018-10-01', 'sum': 70}
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you pls also tell the expected output

Comment: Can you also please include a little more of your data? You've just included 1 object from both `M` and `W`.

Comment: But why do you have 2 similar objects in `Fields`? Won't they have the same sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency:

1. Convert to an object for quicker accessibility
2. Use for loops, not forEach

```js
'use strict';

const M = {
    'ModuleName': 'GDD',
    Fields: [
       {'FieldID': 5, 'Date': '2018-05-01'},
       {'FieldID': 6, 'Date': '2018-05-01'}
      ]
    
};
   
const W = [
         {'FieldID': 5, 'Value': 10, 'WDate': '2018-06-05'},
         {'FieldID': 5, 'Value': 10, 'WDate': '2018-06-05'},
         {'FieldID': 6, 'Value': 50, 'WDate': '2018-07-05'},
         {'FieldID': 6, 'Value': 20, 'WDate': '2018-09-05'}
    ];


let d, e, f = {};
// build object for quicker findability
for (e of M.Fields) {
    f[e.FieldID] = e;
    e.sum = 0;
}

for (e of W) {
    if (d = f[e.FieldID]) {
        if (e.WDate >= d.Date) {
            d.sum += e.Value;
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`could not find FieldID ${e.FieldID}`)
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(M, null, 4));
```